# Generate random number in HTML/CSS that evolves each 5sec

Tags: html, css

Hello so I'm using Shopify and I want to replicake what someone did on this shop
https://www.pancake-malin.com/
http://www.screencast.com/t/cjB8LQLdn

Basically it is a random number generated which evolves each 5 seconds

So I'm quite a beginner with coding.
The dedicaded line is coding in HTML through my theme (page template), so in my case at this URL https://www.tresor-ethnique.com/collections/apache/products/collier-tribal-plumes
I have written: **Plus de 14 commandes en cours !**

Of course I just have a static number for now

I don't know if I just need to insert a HTML code for that, or if I need to insert HTML + CSS in "edit code"

Can anyone let me know?

Thank you :) !

Comment: I'm almost certain you can't generate a random number with just HTML/CSS which is then displayed on your site. Manipulating the DOM is what JavaScript does best. Here's an example:https://www.freecodecamp.org/challenges/generate-random-whole-numbers-with-javascript

Comment: HTML is not a real language, it's a markup (it does not have variables, functions, etc.) Same for CSS, it can't generate variables and doesn't have functions either. You're looking for Javascript :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integration on a list would give:

```
<li class="visite"><strong><span id="update1">80</span><script>   var element1 = document.getElementById('update1');    setInterval(function(){     element1.innerHTML = Math.floor((Math.random()*5)+80);       }, 5000); </script> visiteurs montrent de l’intérêt</strong></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<p>
  Random number between 1 and 10: <span id="update">1</span>
</p>

<script>
  var element = document.getElementById('update'); 
  setInterval(function(){
    element.innerHTML = Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1);   
   }, 5000);
</script>
```

Comment: A huge thanks, I manage to adapt it for my needs and it worked perfectly with the integration

So for my personal culture, is this Javascript?
Thanks :D

Comment: I would have one bonus question, in case it's possible. So I have set random from 8 to 22. Would it be possible to set the new number so that it is between old number-3 and old number+3, and still limited between 8 and 22? I just don't want number evoluate too drastically. I'm aware this might be tricky, let me know, thanks